# Use MIDI Controller for Keyboard Events on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, midi

Is there any way to make a MIDI controller (in this case, a [Gemini FirstMix controller](http://geminidj.com/firstmix)) send keyboard events on Mac OS X? Like I could have it to where when I pressed a button on the controller, a keyboard shortcut would be executed.

Answer (score 0):

[MidiPipe](http://web.mac.com/nicowald/SubtleSoft/MidiPipe.html) might be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[MidiStroke](http://www.charlie-roberts.com/midiStroke/) should do the trick.